# Heapsort in Python does not sorting

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, heapsort

I am new to python and I am trying to implement heapsort from my [C++ implementation](https://github.com/thakurabhi/Algo-Data-Structure/blob/master/Heapsort/C%2B%2B/heapsort.cpp). This code is unable to sort input.

I have written another program to test function `build_max_heap` and this function is unable to build max heap.

```
def max_heapify(thelist, lst_size, idx):
    largest = idx
    left_child = (2 * idx) + 1
    right_child = (2 * idx) + 2

    if left_child < lst_size and thelist[left_child] > thelist[largest]:
        largest = left_child

    elif right_child < len(thelist) and thelist[right_child] > thelist[largest]:
        largest = right_child

    if largest != idx:
        thelist[idx], thelist[largest] = thelist[largest], thelist[idx]
        max_heapify(thelist, lst_size, largest)

def build_max_heap(thelist, lst_size):
    for curr_idx in range(lst_size // 2 - 1, -1, -1):
        max_heapify(thelist, lst_size, curr_idx)

def heap_sort(thelist):
    if len(thelist) == 0:
        print("Empty list!!")

    elif len(thelist) == 1:
        print("Only one element!!")

    else:
        build_max_heap(thelist, len(thelist))

        for curr_idx in range(len(thelist) -1, 0, -1):
            thelist[curr_idx], thelist[0] = thelist[0], thelist[curr_idx]
            max_heapify(thelist, curr_idx, 0)
```

Comment: What is the unused `result = []` list for?

Comment: I modified code but forget to delete it. I will delete it now.

Comment: This line should be `max_heapify(thelist, curr_idx, lst_size)` instead of `max_heapify(thelist, lst_size, curr_idx)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your `heapify` function:

1. The second branch should not be an `elif`, but an `if`, since you'll want to select the right child, even if the left child is greater than its parent, but when the right child is even greater.
2. You don't want to use `len(thelist)` there, as your function should rely on the argument `lst_size`. This is needed because in the `heap_sort` function calls are made that pass a value for this argument that is (and must be) less than the actual list length.

So change:

```
elif right_child < len(thelist) and thelist[right_child] > thelist[largest]:
```

to:

```
if right_child < lst_size and thelist[right_child] > thelist[largest]:
```